# Kubernetes: After mounting volume, pod mounted directory is empty

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-pvc

I have written my own dockerfile for mysql enterprise monitoring application which has mysql backend database. so, I want data directory inside pod to persist. I have mounted data directory to a volume. but, when I entered into my pod and checked data directory there was no files inside data directory. what I observed is it is overwriting already present data directory.

Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
ENV DIR /binaries
ENV PASS admin
WORKDIR ${DIR}
COPY libstdc++-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.rpm ${DIR} 
COPY numactl-libs-2.0.12-3.el7.x86_64.rpm ${DIR}
COPY mysqlmonitor-8.0.18.1217-linux-x86_64-installer.bin ${DIR}
RUN yum install -y libaio && yum -y install gcc && yum -y install gcc-c++ && yum -y install compat-libstdc++-33 && yum -y install libstdc++-devel && yum -y install elfutils-libelf-devel && yum -y install glibc-devel && yum -y install libaio-devel && yum -y install sysstat
RUN yum install -y gcc && yum install -y make && yum install -y apr-devel && yum install -y openssl-devel && yum install -y java
RUN rpm -ivh numactl-libs-2.0.12-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
RUN useradd sql
RUN chown sql ${DIR}
RUN chmod 777 ${DIR}
RUN chmod 755 /home/sql
USER sql
WORKDIR ${DIR}
RUN ./mysqlmonitor-8.0.18.1217-linux-x86_64-installer.bin --installdir /home/sql/mysql/enterprise/monitor --mode unattended --tomcatport 18080 --tomcatsslport 18443 --adminpassword ### --dbport 13306
RUN rm -rf /binaries/*
VOLUME /home/sql/mysql/enterprise/monitor/mysql/data
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/home/sql/mysql/enterprise/monitor/mysqlmonitorctl.sh start && tail -f /home/sql/mysql/enterprise/monitor/apache-tomcat/logs/mysql-monitor.log"]
```

below is my yaml snippet which I deployed in ibm-kubernetes-service

```
Deployment yaml file
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mem     
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mem
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mem
        image: 22071997/mem
        command: 
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/sql/mysql/enterprise/mysql/data
          name: data-volume
      volumes:
      - name: data-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mem-pvc
```

output:

```
[sql@mypod-67cb4f85b8-9km26 data]$ pwd
/home/sql/mysql/enterprise/mysql/data
[sql@mypod-67cb4f85b8-9km26 data]$ ls
[sql@mypod-67cb4f85b8-9km26 data]$
```

Thanks in Advance for helping me :)

Comment: Not sure if this is the only issue but I would *strongly* suggest naming your volume something more unique than simply `volume`. There is a high probability this is causing a conflict with a reserved keyword when the object is being mapped by Kubernetes. Even something as straightforward as `my-volume` would be better.

Comment: A fresh PV will be blank. Why would you expect there to be files there if you didn't put them there?

Comment: @coderanger data directory which I mounted is not empty.....(RUN ./mysqlmonitor-8.0.18.1217-linux-x86_64-installer.bin --installdir /home/sql/mysql/enterprise/monitor --mode unattended --tomcatport 18080 --tomcatsslport 18443 --adminpassword ### --dbport 13306) after this step some files will come under data directory .. which I am supposed to persist. because, Mysql enterprise monitoring is the application which gives you webconsole...from webconsole I'll need to connect to mysql cluster for monitoring purpose...

Comment: When you mount a volume in Linux, everything that was previously under the mountpoint is hidden.

Comment: @coderanger it is not the same in kubernetes

Comment: It is _exactly_ the same in Kubernetes.  (Docker has different behavior only the very first time you start the container, but over the lifecycle of a container/volume I wouldn't rely on it, and Kubernetes doesn't replicate it.)